# Returning a DataTable using Entity Framework By Executing Stored Procedure

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures, dynamic, dynamic-tables

Stored Procedure returns dynamic table which can have dynamic columns. I want to retrieve the list of data to tempResult .

```
IList<SqlParameter> parameters = GetCashInItemsParameters("inv.uspMonthendProces");
string queryString = CreateStoredProcedureExecuteQuery("inv.uspMonthendProcess", parameters);
var tempResult = ExecuteStoredProcedureForDataRetrieve<dynamic>(queryString, parameters.ToArray()).ToList();
```

CreateStoredProcedureExecuteQuery

```
public static string CreateStoredProcedureExecuteQuery(string storedProcedureName, IList<SqlParameter> parameters)
{
            string result = string.Empty;
            string parameterString = string.Join(
                ",", parameters.Select(i => i.ParameterName));
            result = string.Format(
                "{0} {1}", storedProcedureName, parameterString);

            return result;
}
```

CreateParameter

```
public static SqlParameter CreateParameter(string parameterName, object value, SqlDbType dbType)
        {
            SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter(parameterName, dbType);
            param.Value = value;
            param.Value = value ?? (object)DBNull.Value;
            return param;
        }
```

GetCashInItemsParameters

```
public static IList<SqlParameter> GetCashInItemsParameters(string storedProcedureName)
        {
            IList<SqlParameter> parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
            try
            {
                parameters.Add(CreateParameter(
                    "@Year", 2019, SqlDbType.Int));
                parameters.Add(CreateParameter(
                    "@Month", 3, SqlDbType.Int));
                parameters.Add(CreateParameter(
                    "@FromDate", "2019-03-01", SqlDbType.Date));

                parameters.Add(CreateParameter(
                    "@ToDate", "2019-03-31", SqlDbType.Date));
                parameters.Add(CreateParameter(
                    "@CashCentreId",1, SqlDbType.Int));
                parameters.Add(CreateParameter(
                    "@CustomerId", 2, SqlDbType.Int));
                parameters.Add(CreateParameter(
                    "@CurrencyId", 1, SqlDbType.Int));

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }

            return parameters;
        }
```

ExecuteStoredProcedureForDataRetrieve

```
public IList<T> ExecuteStoredProcedureForDataRetrieve<T>(string sqlQuery, params object[] parameters) where T : class
        {
            return db.Database.SqlQuery<T>(sqlQuery, parameters).ToList();
        }
```

This is what i get as result

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRmq6.png)

I tried with `object` , `DataTable` , `DataSet`. But it didnt work either. The project Im working on is using Repository.  So Cannot use Traditional ADO.net

Answer (score 0):

Three things:

1. You misspelled inv.uspMonthendProces
2. You are outputting a parameter, rather than parameter.value for the results.
3. The column that the parameter belongs to is not identified.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter

SqlParameter(String, SqlDbType, Int32, String)
Initializes a new instance of the SqlParameter class that uses the parameter name, the SqlDbType, the size, and the source column name.